# How to create a Progress Bar in access 2010 with multiples queries

Tags: ms-access-2010

i want to add a Progress bar to a form taking in consideration that i am running multiples queries, like 30 queries, and i want the progress bar grows as the queries are being executed.
HERE IS MY CODES:

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim X As Integer
X = MsgBox("Are you Sure you want to Send to Server?????", vbOKCancel, "Are you sure?")
If X = vbOK Then
' If PASSWORD = "222222" Then
Dim intX, intY As Integer

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Me.Refresh
'    DoCmd.Close acForm, "enterpassword"
    With CurrentDb
        intX = DCount("*", "RECORDS IN JobsOrder NOT IN JobsOrder1")
        MsgBox (intX & " RECORDS WILL BE ADDED")
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Jobsorder1_SERVER_WITH_Jobsorder").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Jobsorder2_SERVER_WITH_Jobsorder").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_General1_SERVER_WITH_General").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_General2_SERVER_WITH_General").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Hydrant1_SERVER_WITH_Hydrant").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Hydrant2_SERVER_WITH_Hydrant").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Inspect1_SERVER_WITH_Inspect").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Inspect2_SERVER_WITH_Inspect").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Mains1_SERVER_WITH_Mains").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Mains2_SERVER_WITH_Mains").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Services1_SERVER_WITH_Services").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Services2_SERVER_WITH_Services").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Valves1_SERVER_WITH_Valves").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_Valves2_SERVER_WITH_Valves").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_WortendykeJobs1_SERVER_WITH_WortendykeJobs").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("UPDATE_WortendykeJobs2_SERVER_WITH_WortendykeJobs").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN General NOT IN General1 to General1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN General NOT IN General2 to General2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN Hydrant NOT IN Hydrant1 to Hydrant1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN Hydrant NOT IN Hydrant2 to Hydrant2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN Inspect NOT IN Inspect1 to Inspect1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("Append RECORDS IN Inspect NOT IN Inspect2 to Inspect2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN jobsOrder NOT IN Jobsorder1 to JobsOrder1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN jobsOrder NOT IN Jobsorder2 to JobsOrder2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Mains NOT IN Mains1 to Mains1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Mains NOT IN Mains2 to Mains2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Services NOT IN Services1 to Services1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Services NOT IN Services2 to Services2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Valves NOT IN Valves1 to Valves1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Valves NOT IN Valves2 to Valves2").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Wort NOT IN WortendykeJobs1 to WortendykeJobs1").Execute
        Call .QueryDefs("APPEND RECORDS IN Wort NOT IN WortendykeJobs2 to WortendykeJobs2").Execute
        'Call .QueryDefs("DELETE_Records_JobsOrder").Execute
        Call Me.Requery
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End With
MsgBox ("TRANSFER AND UPDATE HAS BEEN FINISHED!!!")
' Else
 '   MsgBox ("password Invalid!!!")
' End If
Exit Sub
ElseIf X = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this properly (ie not doing a progress bar instruction after each of your `QueryDef` executes), we should be able to loop through all your queries. So the easiest way to do it is to put all your SQL instructions in an `array` or a `collection`, I picked up the latter.

### Form Design

Add to your form 1 rectangle that will be your progress bar background, give it a backcolor and name it *ProgressBarA*

Copy/Paste *ProgressBarA*, name this new rectangle *ProgressBarB* and put it right over *ProgressBarA*, give it another backcolor and make it's width a bit shorter so you can see both rectangles, that's easier. This will be the bar that "fill up"

### Form Code

```
Private colSQL As Collection 

Private Sub Define_SQL_Queries()
        Set colSQL = New Collection

        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Jobsorder2_SERVER_WITH_Jobsorder"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_General1_SERVER_WITH_General"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_General2_SERVER_WITH_General"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Hydrant1_SERVER_WITH_Hydrant"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Hydrant2_SERVER_WITH_Hydrant"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Inspect1_SERVER_WITH_Inspect"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Inspect2_SERVER_WITH_Inspect"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Mains1_SERVER_WITH_Mains"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Mains2_SERVER_WITH_Mains"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Services1_SERVER_WITH_Services"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Services2_SERVER_WITH_Services"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Valves1_SERVER_WITH_Valves"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_Valves2_SERVER_WITH_Valves"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_WortendykeJobs1_SERVER_WITH_WortendykeJobs"
        colSQL.Add "UPDATE_WortendykeJobs2_SERVER_WITH_WortendykeJobs"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN General NOT IN General1 to General1"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN General NOT IN General2 to General2"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN Hydrant NOT IN Hydrant1 to Hydrant1"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN Hydrant NOT IN Hydrant2 to Hydrant2"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN Inspect NOT IN Inspect1 to Inspect1"
        colSQL.Add "Append RECORDS IN Inspect NOT IN Inspect2 to Inspect2"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN jobsOrder NOT IN Jobsorder1 to JobsOrder1"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN jobsOrder NOT IN Jobsorder2 to JobsOrder2"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Mains NOT IN Mains1 to Mains1"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Mains NOT IN Mains2 to Mains2"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Services NOT IN Services1 to Services1"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Services NOT IN Services2 to Services2"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Valves NOT IN Valves1 to Valves1"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Valves NOT IN Valves2 to Valves2"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Wort NOT IN WortendykeJobs1 to WortendykeJobs1"
        colSQL.Add "APPEND RECORDS IN Wort NOT IN WortendykeJobs2 to WortendykeJobs2"
End Sub




Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String

    X = MsgBox("Are you Sure you want to Send to Server?????", vbOKCancel, "Are you sure?")
    If X = vbOK Then
    ' If PASSWORD = "222222" Then
    Dim intX, intY As Integer

    ' REINIT PROGRESS BAR
    ProgressBarB.Width = 0
    Me.Repaint

    ' FILL IN OUR SQL QUERIES COLLECTION
    Define_SQL_Queries


    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Me.Refresh
    '    DoCmd.Close acForm, "enterpassword"
        With CurrentDb
            intX = DCount("*", "RECORDS IN JobsOrder NOT IN JobsOrder1")
            MsgBox (intX & " RECORDS WILL BE ADDED")



            For i = 1 To colSQL.Count
                strSQL = colSQL(i)
                Debug.Print "Executing : " & strSQL
                Call .QueryDefs(strSQL).Execute
                ProgressBarB.Width = (ProgressBarA.Width / colSQL.Count) * i 
                Me.Repaint
            Next i

            Call Me.Requery
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        End With
    MsgBox ("TRANSFER AND UPDATE HAS BEEN FINISHED!!!")
    ' Else
     '   MsgBox ("password Invalid!!!")
    ' End If
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf X = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Not tested but you have the idea. If it doesn't work right away, it should after some minor tweaks

Comment: Hey Thomas G. this codes are OK. I am testing it but i have a Time error '6' overflow. What do you think it is? the debugging windows is sending me to this line      ProgressBarB.Width = (ProgressBarA.Width * i) / colSQL.Count

Comment: Sotty my mistake, I messed up with my computation. It should be `ProgressBarB.Width = (ProgressBarA.Width / colSQL.Count) * i`. I edit my answer

Comment: Now i have another problem it says:
Error 3220 - Function Is Not Available In Expression In Table Level Validation Expression  and it sending me to this line: Call .QueryDefs(strSQL).Execute

Comment: OK i got it. is a Reference problem, i have to do the changes in my main Programming PC. EVERYTHING WORKS AWESOME. Thanks Thomas you are the man.